# proxylist cant be loaded on Scrapy Cloud

Tags: python, scrapy

Module im using  "https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies"
settings as specified and on the PC work perfectly if is link to an existing txt tile on the pc.

I try several time diferente ways on Scrapy Cloud in settings.py file.

I add the file "proxylist.txt" in the same folder than setting than the project in addition i upload it to "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/esdm19mnvz2yguf/proxylist.txt"

I substitute the name in the:
PROXY_LIST = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/esdm19mnvz2yguf/proxylist.txt'
or
PROXY_LIST = 'proxylist.txt'
or
PROXY_LIST = '/proxylist.txt'
PROXY_LIST = '../proxylist.txt'

if i do it like PROXY_LIST = 'proxylist.txt' in my PC, it works like a charm but not once i load it in Scrapy Cloud.

Error i receive.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
self.engine = self._create_engine()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 97, in _create_engine
return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in init
self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/init.py", line 88, in init
self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 36, in from_settings
mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py", line 55, in from_crawler
return cls(crawler.settings)
File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py", line 35, in init
fin = open(self.proxy_list)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../proxylist.txt'`

please i need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not including this file in your `setup.py` instructions.

The mechanism that provides this is the MANIFEST.in file. This is relatively quite simple: `MANIFEST.in` is really just a list of relative file paths specifying files or globs to include.:

```
include README.rst
include docs/*.txt
include funniest/data.json
```

In order for these files to be copied at install time to the package’s folder inside site-packages, you’ll need to supply `include_package_data=True` to the `setup()` function.

See http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html

Comment: i add it. but still wont work.  PROXY_LIST = 'resources/proxylist.txt'    in the manifest.in 'include proxylist.txt
include resources/proxylist.txt
include base_de_datos/resources/proxylist.txt'

Comment: but doesnt work  [link with all my scrapycould project with all the documents](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/b84d2sk8zu8mj34/bases_de_datos.zip) here is my file i already try about 40 times but doesnt work but i run in in my computer it works perfectly, i would like some guidance